# simple GUI for Tibco RV messages?

Tags: user-interface, tibco

I would like a simple GUI that can edit, send and receive Tibco RV messages, for test / development purposes.  Has anyone seen or heard of such a thing?

Comment: but including source-code ... ruling out the only google hit, from TIBCOmmunity (I prefer not to connect unknown class files to my RV server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have heard of some proprietary ones which could do these (and more). 
Searching for open alternatives, here is what I got.

TIBCOmmunity gave the links for a [message monitor](https://www.tibcommunity.com/docs/DOC-2676) called [Anderstool](http://java.net/projects/anderstool). This is a java.net project and so has the source.

Also, in TIBCOmmunity is [TIB RV Test 2.1](https://www.tibcommunity.com/docs/DOC-1149). This also has the source included in it.

Comment: Apparently the links are dead!